# Taking data (movie ID) from one page to make another page about only this one item

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm currently learning web dev and I'm playing with one simple app from the course (making it nicer, adding some more functionality) and I don't know what is a good approach to my current problem.

app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("search");
});

app.get("/results", function(req, res){
    var query = req.query.search;
    request("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&apikey=thewdb", function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render("results", {data: data});
        }
    });
});

app.get("/movie/:imdbID", function(req, res){
    request("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + /* here goes imdbID*/ + "&apikey=thewdb", function(error, response, body) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render("movie", {data: data});
        }
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server is running...");
});
```

search page:

```
<% include partials/header %>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="content">
                <h1>Search Movie</h1>
                <h3>Enter title below to search trough our database</h3>
                <form action="/results" method="GET">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" name="search">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<% include partials/footer %>
```

results page:

```
<% include partials/header %>

<div class="container">
    <div id="result-content">
        <h1>Results Page</h1>
        <h3>Movies matching title you provided</h3>
        <br>
        <h4>Search again...</h4>
        <form action="/results" method="GET">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" name="search">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <% data["Search"].forEach(function(movie) { %>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">
                <img src=" <%= movie["Poster"] %>">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4><a href="/movie/<%= movie["imdbID"] %>"><%= movie["Title"] %> - <%= movie["Year"] %></a></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>

        </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
</div>

<% include partials/footer %>
```

And what I want to do is this - when I get all movies featuring title or part of it provided by user on results page I want to be able to click on any of the movies and go to next page containing details only about the movie I clicked - so bigger poster, cast info, some plot etc. And I have no idea how to pass imdbID of movie being clicked from results page to app.js and make new route to page /results/:id.

Or, maybe my unclear solution is wrong and I should think about using localStorage?

Comment: In your results page, convert or wrap some element (e.g title into a link e.g `<a>` tag that uses the new route as its `href` attribute.  In app.js, implement another handler for the route.  No need for localStorage, use the page URI to carry the necessary data, either as fragment of the path or a query string.

Comment: Ok, I've made a new route in app.js, added link tag in result page around title and it works almost fine - it's going to another page called movie/<imdbID> but I don't know how to pass imdbID from results back to app.js to make second request to movie database by imdbID.

Comment: Can you update your question with the revised code

Comment: Post updated. Link seems to be ok, when I hover over title it shows proper imdbID, I just don't know how or if is it even possible to pass data back to app.js

Comment: In your new app.get, you can use `req.params.imdbID` to access the fragment you defined with `:imdbID` in the uri to match.  Use that where you have the comment `here goes imdbID`.

Comment: Awesome! I knew I'm missing something small yet important. Thank you very much for your help :)